# Deform mesh along another mesh without distortion

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to create a non-destructive piece of road with a curb attached. The road and curve are both controlled with a curve that works fine.

The problem occurs when I wanted to add a SimpleDeform to the road mesh to give me the ability to easily taper its width. What I want is for the curb mesh to stick to the side of the road but not get distorted. The closest I've come is using the Surface Deform modifier on the curb however, this creates bad distortion.

Hopefully, the image helps explain. The ultimate goal is to keep everything non-destructive so I could change the taper and the curb would follow along.

Let me know if you think this is possible. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: The image is not very clear, the resolution is too low. Are you trying to repeat a single block of "road" with an array over a curve with a curve modifier? And then are you trying to do the same with a single block of curb?
Where are the origins of those two base meshes?

Comment: If you only want a color difference then perhaps you can apply a texture.  Perhaps you can join the meshes into one and use two different materials.  Please tell the reader if you think the two ideas are useful. If the basis of your animation were to show vandals peeling off the curb then that would be more difficult.

Comment: So I have a road piece that has an Array modifier then a Simple Deform (set to taper)  and then a Curve modifier and the same on the curb mesh except for the Simple deform. The curve and array allow me to use a curve to define the length and bend but I also wanted to interactively change the taper of the road mesh and have the curb go along with it. If i make them the same mesh and add a taper then the curb mesh will distort which is not what I want. I want it to maintain its shape but still follow along the edge of the road when I use the Simple deform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Deform will give you slightly different results if the objects are not exactly the same. Not very good at deforming multiple objects and keeping them together as far as I know D:

**Try this instead:**

1. Select the first or last control point of the curve.
2. Scale the control point with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or through the N Panel.
3. Select ALL curve points and <kbd>Right Click</kbd> to bring up the Context Menu
4. Select Smooth Curve Radius.

Note that this aligns the curb way better, **but it's still deformed**. Everything you want is certainly possible, but doing it in a way that's 100% non-destructive **and** easy to modify **and** without deforming the curb width... all of that at the same time requires a not so simple setup or a more destructive approach unfortunately (or learning Houdini).

[image]

If you don't mind being more destructive, you can <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the edges of your road (you will have to apply your modifiers to create real geometry first). Then convert those edges to curves and use these new curves as paths for your curbs to follow.